# Is it normal for a square signal to change into a sine shape at high frequencies?

Tags: oscilloscope, waveform

The signal generator outputs a square wave into an LED which emits light onto a photodiode. The photodiode is connected in a TIA circuit and then output is displayed on an oscilloscope.

The output signal starts off square and then gradually changes shape as I increase the frequency of the input square wave. At around 2 MHz the output waveform becomes a sine wave. Is this normal or is there a problem which is causing this?

[image]

The amplifier I am using is an LF351. The typical slew rate is 16 V/μs, but I am not sure about the bandwidth. The oscilloscope has a bandwidth of 500 MHz. I am using a white LED because I am testing the visible spectrum response, but there is no datasheet available for the LED. The LED could be the problem, but no way to know for sure.

Comment: What's the spec for rise and fall time on your signal generator? How are you measuring the signal generator's output?

Comment: If you show us your TIA circuit, we might be able to better guess where in the signal chain bandwidth is limited. If you wish, you could apply a current from function generator into TIA input ( instead of the photodiode current), and see at what frequency its output becomes sinusoidal. If it around 1.5MHz, then TIA is limiting bandwidth.

Comment: Try pulling the LED negative (reverse bias) at high frequencies. For example a +/-5v square wave. This will pull charge out of the junction faster and allow you to more rapidly switch the LED on/off. Also be sure to avoid white LEDs, they use phosphore with a ~100ns fluorescent lifetime and so will filter higher frequencies.

Comment: Just to cover all the bases, what is the bandwidth of your scope?

Comment: To eliminate the scope response as being the issue connect it directly across the signal generator. Do you have any filtering components (eg: capacitors) in your TIA circuit, that could easily be the reducing high frequency response.  Also what are the bandwidth/slew rate specifications for the amplifier you are using for the TIA?

Comment: LF351 seems to have a rated gain bandwidth product of at least 2.5 MHz (and 4 MHz typical), so its maximum gain is around 2 at 1.5 MHz (maybe a bit less than 2, probably a little more).

Comment: @rocky are we done here now? Do you know what to do next --> [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @JerryCoffin so what does this mean?

Comment: @rockky007: op amps are usually specified in terms of gain-bandwidth product (GBW). Lower gain gives higher bandwidth, and vice versa. With 2.5 MHz GBW, you could have a gain of 10 and a bandwith of 2.5MHz/10 = 250 KHz. Or a gain of 100 and a bandwidth of 25 HKz (etc.) A square wave consists of odd harmonics, so let's assume you want the fundamental, 3rd and 5th harmonics and the typical GBW of 4 MHz. That means the highest frequency square wave that will still look reasonably "square" is 4 MHz/5 = 0.8 MHz. By 1.5 MHz, the 3rd harmonic is 4.5 MHz, so even it's probably badly attenuated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661740/why-does-the-amplitude-of-my-output-signal-increase-when-i-increase-frequency-of

Answer (score 3):

Mechanisms that can do what you see: -

- Some LEDs have 100 MHz bandwidth and, some roll-over in the 100s of kHz or less.
- Some signal generators can show poor rise & fall times and ruin the signal integrity
- Your photodiode receiver circuit may have limited bandwidth.

If I were a betting man I'd say the LED is probably the culprit.

Comment: It is probably oscilloscope can not display high frequency.

Comment: That's the least likely but, it can't be ruled out of course @user263983

Comment: I have edited the question with my TIA circuit and some additional information.

Comment: I agree that the white LED is probably not responding because of the time constant of the phosphors. If you need white light, perhaps you can use a RGB LED.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the op-amp is the problem, it's very capable of handling 1.5MHz signals.

White LEDs are known to be slow to illuminate and extinguish due to their phosphors. That's likely to be the main culprit, in my opinion, but you can check by by using a red LED (with no phosphor), and see if this gets you nicer, squarer output.

The junction capacitance of the photodiode may be a few picofarads, and if you've been even a little bit careless with layout (for example you've used a solderless breadboard), stray capacitance anywhere will have a big effect.

I've modelled junction capacitance and a bit of stray capacitance in the feedback, to demonstrate its effect at 1.5MHz:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPD9K5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Photodiode current, simulated by I1:

[image]

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the output is becoming more sine-like, but it's not too bad. You can reduce the photodiode's junction capacitance by increasing its bias potential difference, from -5V to, say, -10V, but don't exceed the diode's maximum reverse voltage (reverse breakdown voltage). Experiment with this to determine how much this capacitance influences the response.

A large part of the problem may be with the LED that's illuminating the photodiode, or its power source. Anything that is influencing the rise and fall of LED voltage, such as its own junction capacitance (possibly nanofarads), or a sluggish source, will be a significant contributing factor. You'll have to examine LED current to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you soo much, I will try with a red LED. The reason I was increasing the frequency was to see the 3dB bandwidth so the point at which the output voltage falls to 0.707 in relation to the maximum output voltage. So I assume I cannot accurately see the 3dB point because high frequencies are being blocked by possibly the white LED?

Comment: @rockky007 If you can't guarantee that the input signal is consistent across all frequencies under test, then your output measurement alone certainly won't be a good indicator of gain! Your output will drop by 3dB if the input drops by 3dB, *OR* if the amplifier's gain drops by 3dB, and you can't know which it is without more information.

Comment: @rockky007 Also a square wave input won't be attentuated *and* remain square at the cut-off frequency, because it has many harmonics that are indiviually attenuated and phase shifted by different amounts. It gets distorted, instead of having its peak-to-peak amplitude changed, making it difficult to assess cut-off frequency using a square signal. The only input which will retain the same shape, and and have it's peak-peak amplitude cut by -3dB at the cut-off frequency is a pure sinusoid.

Comment: I tested the same circuit with an input sine wave. The amplitude of the output sine wave stayed the same until 700kHz and then it started increasing. The amplitude kept increasing until 1.9MHz and then started to fall. Is this normal?

Comment: *You can reduce the photodiode's junction capacitance by reducing its bias potential difference* It's the other way around really: the larger the bias voltage, the narrower the junction, and thus the lower the capacitance. Higher bias voltage speeds things up in that respect, at the cost of higher dark current.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica that was another brain-fart. Thanks for the correction.